# Codeigniter session->userdata() returns the opposite....!

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to fix an issue with permissions in my app, I have a session->userdata('usrclass') set when login with different account class.

I have an ADMIN user who has a usrclass of `ADMIN` and I need to show some content based on that.

BUT when I do this:

```
<?= ($this->session->userdata('usrclass') == "ADMIN") ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>
```

It outputs "no"... While it should output "yes". So I tried reading into the sessiondata with this code:

```
<?= echo $this->session->userdata('usrclass') ?>
```

This outputs the word `ADMIN`... This is a weird behavior, I've tried using `===`, I've tried to figure out other stuff but couldn't.

What could it be?

I'm going to attach some pics of this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: May you could dump `$this->session->userdata('usrclass')`?

Comment: The problem is where you are setting this variable `usrclass`. Try to print the value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be there are some extra whitespace(s) in your session data value, try:

```
<?php
    $sess_data = $this->session->userdata('usrclass');
    $sess_data = trim($sess_data);
    //and echo
    echo ($sess_data == "ADMIN") ? "si" : "no";
?>
```

Comment: Actually I don't know who downvoted you but that is the reason! Thanks I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making sure it's a string coming back from the session.
`((string) $this->session->userdata('usrclass') == "ADMIN") ? 'yes' : 'no';`

Maybe a long shot but could the first userdata('usrclass') be wiping the value. Try removing the test code.
`echo $this->session->userdata('usrclass')`